# How To Protect (make it hard to copy) webpage source code

Tags: html

of course im aware of that hiding a source code of a web page source code is impossible, but is there a way to make it hard to copy.

We have a sticker system which puts out pics in an SVG code so i would like to hide that part...

any one with good tips?

thanks in forwards

Comment: There are any number of ways to obfuscate code, but they're all useless (as you say). Google for HTML/Javascript/CSS obfuscation and take your pick, they're all mostly equally useful/useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way you can somehow achieve what you want is using an obfuscator. It tries to make your code as unreadable as possible. If you want an example of obfuscated code, look at the source code at google.com

have some more inforamtion here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)